# Cleanest way to create class from enum type?

Tags: c#, enums, factory, system.reflection

I have the following enum and classes:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
   MyType1,
   MyType2
}

public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
   public abstract MyEnum GetMyType();
}

public class MySubClass : MyBaseClass
{
   public override MyEnum GetMyType()
   {
      return MyEnum.MyType1;
   }
}
```

I want to create an instance of MySubClass based on GetMyType(), but without the need to "register" the MySubClass to some kind of handler (or is that the way to go?). I know this is probably easy to do via reflection (loop through Assembly for classes which inherit from MyBaseClass and check their MyType), but is that the way to go?

Right now I'm doing something a long the lines:

```
public MyBaseClass CreateMyClass(MyEnum myEnum)
{
   if(myEnum == MyEnum.MyType1)
   {
      return new MySubClass();
   }
   else if(myEnum == MyEnum.MyType2)
   {
      return new MyOtherSubClass();
   }
}
```

Which eventually will result in me forgetting to manually add new classes. It will be caught in a Test, but I'd rather not having to add classes at all since all the information needed is already provided.

Open to all kind of suggestions regarding the best approach.

Comment: Decorate the class with a custom attribute (e.g. `[ClassType(MyEnum.MyType1)]`) and inspect that through reflection? Or revise the entire approach, why do you need this?

Comment: How about a custom attribute applied to enum member with type to be instantiated

Comment: CodeCaster: On a database only the enum-type is stored, not the class information, therefore Enum type needs to be converted into class.

Alex, can you explain a bit more about custom attribute applied to enum member?

Comment: How about generics? You can make a `MyBaseClass<T>` of any type on the fly.

Comment: Sorry Nyerguds, don't see how that helps me since I still need to determine what to instantiate.

Comment: I would rethink this approach. You are tightly coupling your base class with it's derived classes - your base class must be aware of every derived class, and you also must have a member in your enum for it. a generic factory method seems like a more reasonable approach to me.

Comment: So this boils down to some kind of factory class, then. If the enums are the actual class names you can use [`Assembly.CreateInstance(className)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b1f63by(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Zohar: Why would the base class need to be aware of every derived class? I know that an enum for every class must be created, but is necessary, but will be "forced" through the use of the GetMyType()-method.
Nyerguds: Ahh, I can use Alex's approach and use that. The only drawback is that it's not enforced to give each enum an attribute that points to the class it should instantiate. But might be good enough!

Comment: Because it holds the factory method - and needs to be able to instantiate the correct derived class based on the enum value. If your factory method is in a different class, then that class must be aware of all derived types.

Comment: Why not simply use `publc T CreateMyClass<T>() where T : MyBaseClass, new() { return new T();}`?

Comment: Zohar: because I need determine what T is before I actually instantiate. Example:  if(myEnum == MyEnum.MyType1) { return CreateMyClass<MySubClass>()}, which is actual problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a custom attribute to identify desired enum class.

```
public class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyEnum EnumType { get; set; }
}
```

Then the enum and the classes;

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    MyType1,
    MyType2
}
public class MyBaseClass
{

}
[MyCustomAttribute(EnumType = MyEnum.MyType1)]
public class MySubClass : MyBaseClass
{

}
[MyCustomAttribute(EnumType = MyEnum.MyType2)]
public class MyOtherClass : MyBaseClass
{

}
```

You could use `Reflection` to determine the related class with enum.

```
private static Dictionary<MyEnum, Type> _myEnumDictionary = new Dictionary<MyEnum, Type>();

public MyBaseClass GetEnumClass(MyEnum enumType)
{
    if (!_myEnumDictionary.ContainsKey(enumType))
    {
        var enumClass = typeof(MySubClass).Assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetCustomAttributes<MyCustomAttribute>()
                .Any(k => k.EnumType == enumType));
        if (enumClass == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("There is no declared class with the enumType" + enumType);
        }
        _myEnumDictionary.Add(enumType, enumClass);
    }
    return (MyBaseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(_myEnumDictionary[enumType]);
}
```

Finally, you can get instance of the related class like that;

```
var mySubClass = GetEnumClass(MyEnum.MyType1);
var myOtherClass = GetEnumClass(MyEnum.MyType2);
//There is no lookup here. It will get the Type from Dictionary directly.
var mySubClass2 = GetEnumClass(MyEnum.MyType1);
```

Also, you can use a static `Dictionary<MyEnum, Type>` dictionary collection to prevent lookup everytime.

Comment: Thanks for this! It feels like it's something like this I'm looking for. Would you say this is better than placing the Attribute on the enum member instead? If placed on Enum-member no "lookup" would be required each time to instantiate class. (performance vs design?)

Comment: You still need a lookup, but I would cache the values in a `Dictionary<MyEnum, Type>` to make it super speedy.

Comment: Well "yes". In this case we loop through all classes in Assembly, while in "my" suggestion, the Type is known directly from the Enum which would result in (psuedo code):
return (MyBaseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(MyEnumType.GetAttr())

Answer (score 1):

I hope this example solves your question.

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Type1, Type2
}
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    public abstract MyEnum GetMyType();
}
public class MySubClass1 : MyBaseClass
{
    public override MyEnum GetMyType()
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
public class MySubClass2 : MyBaseClass
{
    public override MyEnum GetMyType()
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

So, You have `MySubClass1` and `MySubClass2` as child of your `MyBaseClass`.
Here is your method.

```
    public MyBaseClass CreateMyClass(MyEnum myEnum)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<MyEnum, Type>();
        dict.Add(MyEnum.Type1, typeof(MySubClass1));
        dict.Add(MyEnum.Type2, typeof(MySubClass2));

        var type = dict.Where(x => x.Key == myEnum).Select(x => x.Value);
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type.GetType());
        return (MyBaseClass)instance;
    }
```

Let me explain you in brief.
We are just creating a mapping in a `Dictionary` between the `Enum` and `Type`.
Depending on `Enum` we get in the argument, `Activator` creates instance of the type found from the mapping.

The only catch here is if we put any type other than sub class of `MyBaseClass` in  `dict` dictionary, it will throw runtime exception.

---------------EDIT----------------

If you want to completely avoid mapping, then you can pass the type as `string` argument of the function, and achieve this as below

```
ObjectType instance = 
 (ObjectType)Activator.CreateInstance("MyAssembly","MyNamespace." + argType);
```

Comment: This will also create the problem of always having to manually add new classes. Will not really solve my problem, only move it elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, but we have to keep the mapping somewhere for `Enum` and `Type`. How would code understand it?

Comment: @Whyser : Stormcloak's answer looks neat, but it also puts the mapping somewhere else